# Find Duplicates in Table Plus Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find duplicate phones in TableC (batch 82) but phone is stored in TableD

I need to compare tablec against itself while getting the phone from tabled

Any ideas on how to go about this are appreciated?

```
    SELECT *
    FROM   (SELECT d.phone,
                   d.id
            FROM   tablec c
                   JOIN tabled d
                     ON c.tableid = d.id
            WHERE  c.batch = 82) d
           JOIN (SELECT d.phone,
                        d.id
                 FROM   tablec c
                        JOIN tabled d
                          ON c.tableid = d.id
                 WHERE  c.batch = 82) c
             ON d.phone = c.phone

WHERE  d.id < c.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT d.phone, 
       MIN(d.id) MINID, MAX(d.id) MAXID , COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM   tablec c 
JOIN tabled d 
ON c.tableid = d.id 
WHERE  c.leadlistid = 81
GROUP BY d.phone
HAVING COUNT(*)> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   d.phone,
   count(c.phone)
FROM
   tableD d
   LEFT JOIN tableC c
   ON d.id = c.tableID
/* not sure what you mean by batch 82 -- maybe this: (?)
WHERE
   c.batch = 82
*/
GROUP BY
   d.phone
HAVING
   count(c.phone) > 1
```

Comment: Got it -- the 'find duplicate phones in table c' should have clued me in there.  :-)